Unable to mirror screen from laptop(Ubuntu Lenovo Thinkpad T450) to monitor (Samsung Odessey G4 27 inch)
I am new here and not sure where to post this question, so I have chosen the safe option. I am unable to mirror my screen so please help me.
My setup is

My monitor is :- Samsung odessey g4 27 inch.
My laptop is:- Lenovo Thinkpad T450 which does not have hdmi and has a VGA
I am using VGA to HDMI converter and then connecting HDMI cable to Monitor.

My display option shows two displays when I connect VGA to HDMI.

Built-in display
Unknown display
Shows displays like this

I have already changed this line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  in /etc/default/grub to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=VGA-1:e"  followed by sudo update-grub and a restart.
Output of lspci | grep VGA is as follows
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
The output of xrandr command is as follows
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1600x900      60.01*+  59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

The output of inxi -SMCGx is
System:    Host: user-ThinkPad-T450 Kernel: 5.15.0-105-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20BUS08U00 v: ThinkPad T450 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20BUS08U00 v: SDK0E50510 WIN serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO 
           v: JBET50WW (1.15 ) date: 06/10/2015 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-5300U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 bogomips: 18357 
           Speed: 1397 MHz min/max: 500/2900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1397 2: 1373 3: 798 4: 798 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: i915 resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes

The output of lspci -k -nn -d 8086: is
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 5500 [17aa:5034]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

The output of sudo dmesg | grep -i i915 is
[    4.903363] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    4.925038] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    5.177847] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    5.219833] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.420070] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    6.478715] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device

Thanks

Some VGA to HDMI adapters just do not work. The unknown monitor message is a clue to that.

Thanks for that I was kind of confused with it. So should I try mini display port to hdmi? Will it help? @David
